# IN operator in SQL (PostgreSQL)

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm trying to select with the IN operator in postgreSQL.

When I write:

> select name from table where name = 'Eastway'

or

> select name from table where name like '%Oxford%'

then I have multiple results but

> select name from table where name in ('Eastway', '%Oxford%')

does not return any value.

What am I doing wrong?
And apologies for newbie question.

Comment: I noticed the issue was at upper and lower case strings :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`LIKE` is a regular expresion comparasion

`=` is exact match

Your `IN` is equivalent to `name ='Eastway' OR name = '%Oxford%'`

But if you say on your first query you get multiple result. On your `IN` version should also have some result as well. The rows where `name ='Eastway'`

Comment: I would say `LIKE` is a pattern matching comparison operator, since it does not support regular expressions. For regexes there is another `SIMILAR` or `~` operators. http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/functions-matching.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use `or` for this.  Or a regular expression:

```
select name
from table
where name ~ '(^Eastway$)|Oxford';
```